# Depth test not woking

Tags: c, opengl, glut

Well, I have a .obj, and a rectangle, but even with `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)`, obj is always behind the rectangle.

I translated my obj to a point very close to the screen, but even though it is behind the rectangle.

A little of my code:

In the main code:

```
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
```

Before any draw:

```
glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -300.0f);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

Before the rectangle:

```
glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 310.0f);
```

in function Changesize:

```
gluPerspective(45.0f, fAspect, 0.1, 425.0);
```

Comment: Have you checked your `glDepthFunc` setting?

Comment: No, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you request some depth buffer bits from the operating system when you create your context.

You may not get any by default.

You can check how many you have via `glGetIntegerv()` and `GL_DEPTH_BITS`.

Comment: Hm... could you explain me better please?

Comment: For depth testing to work you need a depth buffer to write to/read from.  Simply enabling `GL_DEPTH_TEST` is insufficient.  To get a depth buffer you have to request one from the OS when you create your GL context.  If you're using GLUT to create your context you can simply `| GLUT_DEPTH` onto your `mode` for `glutInitDisplayMode()`.  Other frameworks require other procedures.  If you specify the one you're using in your question you can get more targeted answers.

Comment: Oh, I got it now... but sadly I'm already using it :/ I edited my post with this info